# Using "if" "else" in smarty table?

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, smarty, smarty3

Here's the code I'm using for my table:

```
<tbody>
      {foreach key=num item=referral from=$referrals}
      {if $referral.commission neq "$0.00 USD"}
      <tr>
        <td>{$referral.date}</td>
        <td>{$referral.service}</td>
        <td>{$referral.amountdesc}</td>
        <td>{$referral.commission}</td>
        <td>{$referral.status}</td>
      </tr>
      {/if}
      {foreachelse}
        <tr>
           <td colspan="6">{$LANG.norecordsfound}</td>
        </tr>
      {/foreach}
</tbody>
```

Basically if `$referral.commission` is `$0.00 USD` then I don't want that row to show.  However, right now those rows are showing and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: What is an example of a `$referral.commission`? Maybe it's just a number, without the `USD` part.

Comment: Where is your `{if...}`?

Comment: It would equal `$0.00 USD` or `$100.00 USD` or `$200.00 USD` or `$300.00 USD`

Comment: @sectus look on the second line

Comment: @user3205164 The string must be something different, just debug it.

Comment: In the code you can see where I have `<td>{$referral.commission}</td>` - that showed exactly `$0.00 USD`

Comment: are you using smarty 2 or 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your quotes. Use single quotes and change the if statement to `'$0.00 USD'` instead of using double quotes.

```
<tbody>
      {foreach key=num item=referral from=$referrals}
      {if $referral.commission != '$0.00 USD'}
      <tr>
        <td>{$referral.date}</td>
        <td>{$referral.service}</td>
        <td>{$referral.amountdesc}</td>
        <td>{$referral.commission}</td>
        <td>{$referral.status}</td>
      </tr>
      {/if}
      {foreachelse}
        <tr>
           <td colspan="6">{$LANG.norecordsfound}</td>
        </tr>
      {/foreach}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<tbody>
{foreach key=num item=referral from=$referrals}
{if $referral.commission neq "$0.00 USD"}
<tr>
  <td>{$referral.date}</td>
  <td>{$referral.service}</td>
  <td>{$referral.amountdesc}</td>
  <td>{$referral.commission}</td>
  <td>{$referral.status}</td>
</tr>
{else}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">{$LANG.norecordsfound}</td>
    </tr>
{/if}
{/foreach}
</tbody>
```

For more details to use if/else inside foreach loop refer http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl

Comment: Why did you get rid of foreachelse??

Comment: this is also one method by which he can use if/else inside foreach

Comment: foreachelse works totally differently then your else... read docs you pasted!

Comment: @user3205164 `foreachelse` is for records not found. Read the question again.

Comment: insert double quotes in `{foreach key=num item=referral from=$referrals}` for key and item as `{foreach key="num" item="referral" from=$referrals}`